# getDateTime doesn't exist - what to use instead?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jodatime, resultset

I have this problem that I have used `DateTime` from `Joda` and when I try to `getDateTime` it of course won't work because ResultSet doesn't have the method. What should I use instead?

I asked a similar question yesterday where I tried to `setDateTime` and that worked fine but this time I am not sure what to do. I could use `getTimeStamp` but then I have to change my data according to and that's not appropriate I think. Is there a good workaround here? I much appreciate your help.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Contingent c = new Contingent(rs.getInt("contingent_id"),
        rs.getDateTime(("contingent_start_Date"),
        rs.getDateTime("contingent_end_date"),
        rs.getInt("member_id"));

    contingentInfo.add(c);
}
```

Comment: explain clearly what you want to ask,*I could use getTimeStamp but then I have to change my data according to and that's not appropriate I think*

Comment: I want to getDateTime since I am using DateTime in my constructor.

Comment: what is column datatype?

Comment: It's a Date but I am still using DateTime because it's recommended.

Comment: You mean to say that you are storing a `date` in database but using a `DateTime` in your code?

Comment: Yes, is that very wrong to do?

Comment: I was thinking about storing the time as well in the future.

Comment: @ilhami use timestamp datatype to store date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following statement should be working:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime( rs.getTimeStamp( your_column_index ).getTime() );
```

and alternatively

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime( rs.getDate( your_column_index ).getTime() );
```

***Refer to***:
[DateTime( long instant )](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29)

In reference to [Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262172/getdatetime-doesnt-exist-what-to-use-instead/20262634?noredirect=1#comment30225950_20262634), there exist other Constructors in the JodaTime's DateTime API, that take an input representing a Date or timestamp.

***Please also Refer to***:
[***Joda Time: org.joda.time.DateTime Constructors Summary***](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#constructor_summary)

Comment: You don't even need the .getTime(). DateTime has constructors that will convert Dates, Timestamps, Calendars...

Comment: @Kayaman I could not find such a [DateTime constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#constructor_summary) in the list. Can you please refer it here?

Comment: It's [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29) one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTimestamp()`, then convert it to a `DateTime`.

```
DateTime readTheJavadoc = new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp(1));
```

Comment: Ok I will try to use Timestamp.